# Activity recognition using Android accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, gesture-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Store orientation to an array - and compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368618/store-orientation-to-an-array-and-compare)
>   [Processing accelerometer data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453517/processing-accelerometer-data)

I'm developing a mobile application using Android in which I want to determine the activity of the user (mainly walking and standing) using the accelerometer sensor. Does anybody know about some free libraries to employ or to start from? Since I'm working with Android I'm looking for something lightweight. I couldn't find much on google apart from dozens of theoretical papers.

I understand it's a pretty broad question, but I think it can help everybody in the same situation.

Thank you!

Comment: Read [Motion Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) first

Comment: Yes, I think I got the solution. Right now I am implementing the k-Nearest Neighbour algorithm as I needed an algorithm running realtime on the device and from some researches, I found out that this algorithm is suggested for online recognition since it is lightweight

Comment: @user1135357 Please post the solution if the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose all the links will be the most important for understanding how to do it.The link is as follows:-[Imp Link for Understanding](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel) with another link:-[Main Link with Example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472).

Try this link too:-[Explaining with Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html) with this link too:-[Stacks link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274129/how-to-use-accelerometer-values-to-move-an-image-in-android). Now this link is pretty useful which includes:-[Accelerometer Basic Usage](http://indyvision.net/2010/03/android-accelerometer-basic-usage/) and also [use the accelerometer](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/use-the-accelerometer).